# React native <RNDatePicker> not closing on first try

Tags: react-native

so i have a component that uses textinput and rndatepicker
it works like this: 
1) when textinput is focused datepicker must appear.
2) after selecting date the value of textinput changes to selected date.
my problem is im having to close the modal twice and the other components value changes with the operation on current component.
here is the code

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {Modal, Platform} from 'react-native';
import {TextInput} from 'react-native-paper';
import RNDatePicker, {Event} from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker';
import moment from 'moment';
interface IProps {
  value: string;
  onChange: (value: string, date: Date | undefined) => void;
}
const isIOS = Platform.OS === 'ios';
let visible = false;
const DatePicker = ({value, onChange}: IProps) => {
  const [isVisible, setVisible] = React.useState(false);

  const renderDatePicker = () => {
    const datepicker = (
      <RNDatePicker
        value={value ? moment(value).toDate() : new Date()}
        minimumDate={value ? moment(value).toDate() : new Date()}
        onChange={(_: Event, date: Date | undefined) => {
          onChange(moment(date).format('YYYY/MM/DD'), date);
          visible = !visible;
        }}
        display="calendar"
      />
    );
    return isIOS ? (
      <Modal
        transparent
        visible={isVisible}
        supportedOrientations={['portrait']}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          setVisible(false);
        }}>
        {datepicker}
      </Modal>
    ) : (
      datepicker
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <TextInput
        value={value ? moment(value).format('YYYY/MM/DD') : ''}
        onFocus={() => {`
          setVisible(!visible);
          visible = true;
        }}
        onBlur={() => {
          setVisible(false);
          visible = false;
        }}
        keyboardAppearance="dark"
        style={{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}
      />
      {/* { if(visible) renderDatePicker()} */}
      {visible && renderDatePicker()}
    </>
  );
};
export default DatePicker;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use onChange/onFocus function as per below ...

```
const onChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
    if (selectedDate === undefined) {
      setVisible(false);
    } else {
      setDate(currentDate);
    }
  };
```

ref. https://github.com/react-native-community/datetimepicker